# Ionic windows Support

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ionic2

> Sorry for being stupid. But I am looking for these answers.

1. Does Ionic 2 supports Windows 10 Mobile (Phone) and Windows 10
       Universal App?  If yes then how to proceed with windows phone and universal app execution with one windows folder being created
   after doing ionic platform add windows.
2. I am presuming we can use Angular 1.X with Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ionic 2 supports Windows 10 Mobile (Phone) and Windows 10 Universal App?

Yes, like you can see [here](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-windows-support-in-ionic-2/) since Ionic2 beta.3 Universal Windows Platform Apps are officially supported.

> If yes then how to proceed with windows phone and universal app
>   execution with one windows folder being created after doing ionic
>   platform add windows.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNQHd1n6Sog) you can find a tutorial to see what to do after building the app for windows platform.

> I am presuming we can use Angular 1.X with Ionic 2.

Unfortunately, that's not possible. Ionic 2 is built on top of Angular 2, so you **can not** use Angular 1.X in your Ionic 2 application.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Windows 10 Universal I assume for windows machines and few surface devices. But does Ionic too support windows 10 mobile which includes windows phones.